# need to show a complex function is continuous on C (complex plane)

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove $$f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!}$$ is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{C}$

I want to show, for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $|z-w| < \delta \longrightarrow |f(z) - f(w)| < \epsilon$, $\forall z,w \in \mathbb{C}$

So, since by the power series definition of $cos(z)$, we have $f(z) = cos(z)$.

We have $|cos(z) - cos(w)| < \epsilon \longrightarrow -\epsilon < cos(z) - cos(w) < \epsilon $, doing $cos^{-1}$ to all sides gives us:

$|z-w| < cos^{-1}(\epsilon)$, then let $\delta = cos^{-1}(\epsilon)$ and we have what we wanted.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, and imo much simpler, way. Put

$$a_n:=\frac{z^{2n}(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\implies\;$$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\left|\frac{z^{2n+2}(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{z^{2n}(-1)^n}\right|=|z|^2\frac1{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

and thus the series' radius of convergence is infinite, which means the series defines an analytic function for every $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$ ...

Comment: interesting, do you think my answer is correct though? i'm a little iffy on the delta

Comment: @user133269, I'm not sure that was the intention of the one asking the question. If you already know the series defines such a nice, cute function as $\;\cos z\;$ then the gist of the question is lost, imo. Perhaps you can do it as I showed, or else you'll have to deal with differences of infinite series and directly show it. I can't tell. If you use $\;\cos z\;$, why then not to use directly $\;\cos z=\frac12\left(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\right)\;$ and use the analicity of the exponential?

Comment: this is beyond me lol

Answer (score 0):

in power series $$\cos z=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!}$$

and cosine function is continuous every where

Comment: this is **exactly** what the OP did in the body of the question...